# Reconnect Ethernet

Tags: raspbian, networking, ethernet

Recently I noticed that with Raspbian 10, when I unplug ethernet and plug it in again, Wicd won't reconnect. Before, with Raspbian 9 I could just unplug ethernet and plug it in when I wish, and it would automatically reconnect. How do I make it reconnect automatically?

Comment: Raspbian doesn't use Wicd. It works perfectly with default networking - see [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: Are you sure? Because I certainly didn't install it myself and when I upgraded to Raspbian 10 it was installed and is now launched every boot

Comment: Absolutely positive. Raspbian has been using `dhcpcd` since May 2015 - See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697). NOTE upgrading Raspbian is NOT officially supported - the Foundation recommends fresh installation. Those who ignore this advice have a lot of patching to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem first by installing dhcpcd by running `# apt-get install dhcpcd dhcpcd-gtk` and then by uninstalling wicd by using `# apt purge wicd`, then `# apt autoremove`. Now if I unplug ethernet and reconnect it, it reconnects automatically.